# How would I convert a set of Styles to DataTemplates for an enum type?

Tags: wpf

Currently we have an enum type where each unique value is being represented by a unique style:

```
<Style x:Key="EnumValue1" TargetType="CheckBox">
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
<Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 1 0" />
<Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
<Setter Property="Height" Value="18" />
<!-- ... common property setters etc. -->

<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Border>
                <StackPanel>
                    <!-- custom enum value-specific control content -->
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                    </Trigger.Setters>
                </Trigger>
                   <!-- ... custom triggers etc ... -->
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

Currently the Checkboxes are being created programmatically in code-behind - I'm changing this to a ListBox bound to a collection of these enum values and I think it makes sense to convert these to a DataTemplate instead - question is, how do I maximize re-use?

I have roughly 10 unique values and 10 unique styles ...9/10 of the styles use the same Setters, the ControlTemplate.Triggers are the same for all 10 but obviously the visual tree in the ControlTemplate is different

I thought about using a base Style class and having each specific-variant derive / override it with another Style and use a StyleSelector, but then how would I vary the ControlTemplate visual tree per style without having to re-define the triggers?

But this seems 'philosophically' wrong ...I feel like I should be using DataTemplates, because this is by definition what they're meant to be use for

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a ValueConverter that evaluates the enum value and returns the appropriate template?

```
public enum TemplateEnum
{
    firstValue,
    secondValue
}

public class TemplateConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        var templateEnum = (TemplateEnum)value;
        switch (templateEnum)
        {
            case TemplateEnum.firstValue:
                return Application.Current.Resources["FirstValueTemplate"];
            case TemplateEnum.secondValue:
                return Application.Current.Resources["SecondValueTemplate"];
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}

<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding EnumVal, Converter={x:Static local:Converters.templateConverter}}" />
```

Comment: That works, but couldn't I use an ItemTemplateSelector class in that case?

To be honest, I'm more interested in what strategy I should use in how I should manage my Styles / DataTemplates that would minimize redundancy and be more manageable, than how to wire them up

Comment: I want to use data templates instead of styles so that they are a function of the data-type and their values ..right now I don't like how the Styles are written against checkboxes

Comment: Unless I am not understanding your intention, you should be able to leverage the same solution from anywhere in the scope of the binding. For instance, if the checkbox that this style belongs to is within a datatemplate inside an itemscontrol then you can use the converter to implement a datatemplate selection defined as an application resource.

If it were me, I would use the converter in lieu of the ItemTemplateSelector, as I find the implementation to be cleaner and more scalable.

I hope this helps.